# Issue with arrays using Swift: Can't access all objects of an array after For loop

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I've had this problem for a very long time. I'm trying to populate a     `UITableView` with `NSMutableArray`. But I'm not getting all the objects out side of the loop. The total count of objects is 167. But instead it returns 167 of the same object.

> I declared the array outside of the loop like this:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var sermon = SermonLink()
var sermons: NSMutableArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadContent()
   }
```

> The whole thing happens in a method:

```
func loadContent() {

var elements: NSArray = []


    let urlForHTML = NSURL(string:"http://ontherock.dk/?page_id=1141")
    var dataForHTML: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlForHTML!)!
    var htmlParser = TFHpple(HTMLData: dataForHTML)
    var htmlXPathString = "//td[@class='lyf_td_filename']/a"
    elements = htmlParser.searchWithXPathQuery(htmlXPathString) as NSArray

        var sermonArr:NSMutableArray = []
        for item in elements {
            var element: TFHppleElement = item as! TFHppleElement

            var firstChildItem: NSString = element.firstChild.content
            var dashSeperatedSermonArray = firstChildItem.componentsSeparatedByString("-") as! [String]


            sermon.subject = dashSeperatedSermonArray[4].stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
            sermon.speaker = dashSeperatedSermonArray[3].stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
            sermon.urlForAudioSermon = element.attributes["href"] as! String



            sermonArr.addObject(sermon)//Here inside the loop I get the expected data
        }
        sermons = sermonArr //sermons contains only the object at the last index, 167 times
        self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Comment: Is `SermonLink` a class?

Comment: Amit89 is right, you are modfying the same `sermon` object over and over. You need to create a new `sermon` object *inside the loop* before the lines `sermon.subject = ...`

Comment: Yes `SermonLink` is a class. Okay. I'll try declaring the object inside as you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below could be the problem.

Since you initialised the `var sermon = SermonLink()`
 as a property of the class and you are updating same objects inside the for loop. Try to create this inside the for loop for each iteration.